# how to remove trailing zeros showing in my data description in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I remove trailing zeros showing in my data description in Jupyter notebook?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, please don't paste images of your code or results. See here for more https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

`pd.set_option('precision', 1)` might help.